# Dplyr Summarise on Multiple Conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, lubridate, satellite

So I am working on some data visualisations of satellite populations, I would like to display for each month and altitude, how many satellites were launched into each orbit.

I have a list (snippet below, which is fake data). I am trying to create a bubble plot, where for each date (grouped by month) on the X axis, the altidude (grouped by 100km) and then the size of the bubble would be the count (shown in the second table).

| COSPAR_ID | LAUNCH_DATE | ALTITUDE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IRIDIUM 180 | 2019-01-01 | 1150 |
| IRIDIUM 176 | 2019-02-01 | 1250 |
| RISESAT | 2019-04-06 | 1150 |
| RAPIS-1 | 2019-03-01 | 1375 |
| MICRODRAGON | 2019-05-01 | 400 |
| NEXUS (FO-99) | 2019-04-01 | 459 |
| ALE-1 | 2019-05-01 | 1000 |
| IRIDIUM 167 | 2019-04-01 | 900 |
| IRIDIUM GSAT-31 | 2019-0-01 | 666 |
| IRIDIUM 188 | 2019-06-01 | 1000 |
| IRIDIUM 111 | 2019-02-01 | 1250 |
| IRIDIUM 123 | 2019-01-01 | 1150 |

| LAUNCH_DATE | ALTITUDE | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-19 | 0-500 | 10 |
| Jan-19 | 500-1000 | 100 |
| Jan-19 | 1000-1500 | 150 |
| Feb-19 | 0-500 | 20 |
| Feb-19 | 500-1000 | 90 |
| Feb-19 | 1000-1500 | 150 |

So far, I am getting quite lost. I am using dplyr to be able to summarise first by the month, and then starting to count altitudes.

```r
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(month = lubridate::floor_date(LAUNCH_DATE, 'month')) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(count), 
            sumA = n(ALTITUDE < 100))
```

My next steps would be to group the altidudes first, then summarise by the date? I am hitting a brick wall. So not sure where to go next? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Happy to add the original dataset of satellites, just quite a large file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cut()` to make your bins, defining your breaks and labels beforehand:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

alti_breaks <- seq(0, by = 500, length.out = ceiling(df$ALTITUDE / 500) + 1)
alti_labs <- paste(head(alti_breaks, -1), tail(alti_breaks, -1), sep = "-")

df <- df %>%
  count(
    LAUNCH_DATE = floor_date(LAUNCH_DATE, 'month'),
    ALTITUDE = cut(ALTITUDE, alti_breaks, alti_labs),
    name = "COUNT"
  )

df
```

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  LAUNCH_DATE ALTITUDE  COUNT
  <date>      <fct>     <int>
1 2019-01-01  1000-1500     2
2 2019-02-01  1000-1500     2
3 2019-03-01  1000-1500     1
4 2019-04-01  0-500         1
5 2019-04-01  500-1000      1
6 2019-04-01  1000-1500     1
7 2019-05-01  0-500         1
8 2019-05-01  500-1000      2
9 2019-06-01  500-1000      1
```

And the bubble plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(LAUNCH_DATE, ALTITUDE)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = COUNT), color = blues9[[6]], show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: A massive thank you <3 This is exactly what I needed :) If you are interested, this was my final plot:
https://i.postimg.cc/k4TbzT9w/Monthly-Satellite-Launches-by-Perigee-KM.png

Comment: Nice! Note you could use `tidyr::drop_na(ALTITUDE)` (or `filter(!is.na(ALTITUDE))`) to remove the top row of `NA`s from your plot.